# SQL - can a table get its own name via alias column/field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**product:**

```
id
```

**image:**

```
id
imageable_type
imageable_id
```

---

I am trying to execute a query to the effect of:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN image i
    ON i.imageable_id = p.id 
    AND i.imageable_type = "product"      # <--this
```

But due to the constraints of my application framework, I must append a field name to the alias `p.`, so I am looking for something to the effect of:

`AND i.imageable_type = p.TABLE_NAME      # <--this`

where `TABLE_NAME` is some built in "universal special field" so-to-speak that references name of the parent table. Is there such as feature in MySQL or other SQL db's?

Comment: Do you want to return table name as a column in the output?

Comment: @Alex no, I want to join on where  `i.imageable_type = ` table name.

Comment: In sql (or mysql) the table name must be explicit ..  you can do this kind of things using procedural code and dinamically generated code ..

Comment: Is the DB schema fixed?

Comment: You can't use p.TABLE_NAME because is the same of table_name.table_name .this is wrong .. you can use eg. AND i.imageable_type = p.column_name    ( column_name must be a proper column name of the table p alias product)

Comment: Please specify what fremawork you are using. Based on updated question and comments above this is a problem with your framework and not SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Would your framework accept this?

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
INNER JOIN image i
    ON i.imageable_id = p.id 
WHERE i.imageable_type = "product"
```